# Have GDB frames point to file and not the library?

Tags: gdb

I have a backtrace in GDB that has frames pointing to a `.so` object which I compiled myself from source files. How can I make GDB frames point to source files instead of the `.so` object?

To illustrate, I would like this:

```
#0  FuncA (...) at path/to/fileA.c:741
#1  0x00000000004e01c6 in FuncB (...) from path/to/mylib.so
#2  0x0000000000436c75 in FuncC (...) from path/to/mylib.so
```

to turn to this:

```
#0  FuncA (...) at path/to/fileA.c:741
#1  0x00000000004e01c6 in FuncB (...) at path/to/fileB.c:123
#2  0x0000000000436c75 in FuncC (...) at path/to/fileC.c:234
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while typing the above question: I had to compile the `mylib.so` with `-ggdb3` flag.